# Как скачать картинку из URL и сделать его bitmap в kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
var bitmap1: Bitmap? = null
var url = "https://i.ibb.co/F3k0101/hero-man.png"
```

Как картинку из Url закинуть внутрь переменной bitmap1?

Comment: Вроде тут неплохо описано https://stackoverflow.com/a/38325840/13941944

Comment: этот метод выводит ошибку не работает

Comment: что за ошибка, что именно не работает. Приложите код как делали, что в логах.

Comment: если делать с HttpURLConnection, то на строчке  connection.connect() выходит ошибка, видимо оно выпилено из новых версий андройда как устаревшая, а через Пикасо можно только в ImageView таргетировать, а в переменную сохранить нельзя @AVRamones

Comment: а если так :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11831325/13941944

Comment: @AVRamones не вышло так же выбивает ошибку

Comment: а покажите лог ошибки плиз

Comment: @AVRamones тут вылетает из приложения

Comment: Описанная вами задача - сложная задача. Если прикидывать по библиотеке Glide - чтобы сделать нормально надо около 100 программистов, 4 года и 2500+ коммитов. Вывод - берите Glide библиотеку и её используйте. Иначе вам придётся самостоятельно решать проблемы многопоточности, потребления памяти, кэширования, работы на разных версиях ОС, масштабирования картинок etc.

Comment: я попробовал сделать такую конструкцию https://stackoverflow.com/a/41804371/14366005 но скачанную картинку нельзя использовать если не подождать определенное время, выбивает ошибку @ЮрийСПб

Comment: "выбивает ошибку" можно интерпретировать несколькими тысячами (буквально) способов. Всегда прикладывайте лог ошибки и место её возникновения в коде. Если я правильно вас понял (а это не факт, т.к. вы даёте очень мало информации для обоснованных предположений) то у вас всё работает как надо. В главном потоке загрузить что-то с сервера в общем случае не получится - это ограничение операционной системы на уровне фреймфорка. Стройте логику так, что картинка загрузится неизвестно когда и вообще не факт, что загрузится.

Comment: Вы работает с сетью на телефоне - сеть может быть медленной, её вообще может не быть либо она пропадёт в процессе загрузки. Всё это надо учитывать. И оно учтено на уровне запрета запрсов в сеть из главного потока. Засим и картинка может придти только в Callback неизвестно когда и то только с некоторой вероятностью

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рекомендую юзать Glide

```
    Glide.with(context)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(url)
        .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                // твой код
            }

            override fun onLoadFailed(errorDrawable: Drawable?) {}

            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {}
        })
```

Comment: Вот этот ответ подходит больше всего!

Answer (score 0):

Такой вот вариант:

```
 try {
        val url = URL("http://....")
        val image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream())
    } catch (e: IOException) {
    }
```

Comment: я попробовал, это сейчас не работает в логах пишет  Process: com.themarkbrutx.mymodeapp, PID: 17278
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.themarkbrutx.mymodeapp/com.themarkbrutx.mymodeapp.test.TestBitmapActivity}: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException

Comment: @Riprup ну так у вас проблема не с этим участком кода, судя по логам. Вы совсем плаваете что к чему в ошибках пишется?